# In java could increase the value of a float by a value each time a button is pressed? (and also decrease)

Tags: java

Could I use something like

```
sh=current_value

if button_pressed=true{
this.sh='current_value'+0.5f
};
```

I think this can probably be done but I am not very experienced in java programming so I am not sure how to do this, so could you please help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjavax%2Fswing%2FJButton.html&ei=2Z9OVMjyDPLGsQTly4GwDQ&usg=AFQjCNFwtfUDpO35cMSq9rjz7bwhUEKZAw&sig2=IhK0Go8QYEVF3XySBN_7fQ&bvm=bv.77880786,d.cWc and https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2Fevents%2Factionlistener.html&ei=6J9OVPagH8S1sQSAq4CwDQ&usg=AFQjCNFp3dH1WtGwb_Qf_ci4bYGqzfhL4Q&sig2=sjJDf1mUQgGGlvNwIYeGqQ

Comment: You have a long way to go yet. You need to familiarize yourself with the Swing API and its various funtimes with different components (such as buttons) and eventListeners and -Handlers! Good luck on your journey, young padawan. I suggest googling "Java GUI tutorial" or "Java Swing tutorial"

Comment: Flagged as too broad, because OP is asking a question that is probably beyond his/her current programming skills, and a correct answer that he could understand would have to dwell deep into how to make and show gui, make & add buttons, eventlisteners etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Something like" that, yes.  Look at the [tutorial on JButtons.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)  You need to add an action listener to the button, which then executes the code you want.

```
       JButton b = new JButton( "Click me." );
       ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
          float value = 42f;
          @Override public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
             value += 0.5f;
          }
       };
       b.addActionListener( al );
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't explain earlier that I had everything set up except for the increasing of the float, so using your advice I did it using this

```
Case 0:
    this.sh=sh+=0.5f;
```